# Photoshop action to set marquee width and height

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-action

For iPhone and iPad screenshots, I like to crop out the status bar. I can never remember the exact pixel dimensions to enter into the marquee tool and when I do find out, it's fiddly to enter it. Is there a way to make a Photoshop action to do the following:

- Set the Marquee style to "Fixed Size"
- Set the Marquee Width and Height to specific values
- Set the Marquee back to "Normal" Style

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the selection marquee tool, use the crop tool. Make a crop tool *preset* with your desired dimensions 640x920(-statusbarpixels). Now just select your crop tool and the new preset and draw the crop rectangle from the bottom and up. Press Enter and you are done. The selection tool remains in whatever mode you wish it to be.